# Session data between servlets within a cluster

Tags: java, grails, load-balancing, spring-webflow

So I'm not entirely certain how to word this question to ask it properly. I'll simply put down what I know of the situation, requirements, and ideas to paint the picture.

I have two servlets: one is a grails 2.1.1 servlet and another is a Spring Webflow servlet. I've been tasked with inserting an iframe of the grails servlet into a page on the Spring Webflow servlet. The issue I of course raised was one of session data. The servlets are deployed to tomcat on the same server yet there are 3 servers in the cluster (all 3 servers have both servlets on them). Sticky sessions are enabled. My question is this: will I even be able share session data between the two servlets? I'd imagine that an iframe would produce a new jsession id for the grails app. If I can share data between the two servlets, how would that be accomplished? Using the typical getAttribute/setAttribute functions?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Why don't you use web services?

Comment: The idea was to add the form of the grails app to the existing web flow application. I'm actually looking into using web services as it would greatly reduce complexity. Thanks for the input and reassurance that web services are a far sounder way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup, you can't share the data between different tomcat session directly. You have 2 options here:

1. Use a medium between your tomcats for sharing and exchanging data, like database or some in-memory cache.
2. Send all data you want within a http-request directly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Memory caching seems to be a bit of a sledgehammer to a walnut given the scope of the project. Option 2 (in the form of a restful service as noted by @Armaiti ) is what I went with. To protect sensitive elements, jasypt was used to obfuscate the data.